# Условие для экспорта в csv на powershell

Tags: powershell

Прошу помощи!

Есть следующий код:

```
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://dc=dc,dc=ru"
$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
$users = $objSearcher.FindAll()
$users | ForEach-Object {
   $user = $_.Properties
   New-Object PsObject -Property @{
   Человек = [string]$user.mail
   Кто = [string]$user.title
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoClobber -Encoding utf8 -Path  C:\list_user.csv
```

Необходимо добавить условие: экспортировать mail и title только тех person, у которых $user.mail входит в ряд маилов (около 300). Я пробовала к вышеупомянутому коду добавить

```
| where-object {$_.user.mail in "A.Zenina@dc.ru, Vasiliy.Ivanovich@dc.ru, Evgeniya.Zaiteeva@dc.ru"}
```

,но безрезультатно.

Comment: а в какое место пробовали добавить ?

Comment: В конец. А куда нужно?

Comment: `$users  | where-object {$_ ... } | ForEach-Object {` а так пробовали?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor пробовала. выдает пустые поля, а их количество(еще добавила $users.Count) такое же, как и без  where-object. А данные адреса точно есть в указанной мною ветке.

Comment: попробуйте `$mails = "A.Zenina@dc.ru", "Vasiliy.Ivanovich@dc.ru", "Evgeniya.Zaiteeva@dc.ru" \n $users | where-object {$mails -contains $_.user.mail} | ForEach-Object {`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor падает с ошибкой :(

Comment: обновите вопрос и приложите новый код и ошибку